# How do I combine two variables with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that collects first name and last name via two div elements:

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="last name" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="first name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In the script I have the following line

```
const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
```

What I would like to do is produce a constant called fullname which comprises of firstname+lastname

How can I rewrite the line starting with const above to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one should be fairly simply. You already have a way of extracting the value of the `lastName` input. So just do the same for `firstName` and then concatenate the two variables.

```js
const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;

const fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
```

Comment: I noticed that in the HTML you have first name spelled with a lowercase "n" instead of an uppercase"N". If you had tried this solution and it didn't work that may have been your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing syntax:

```
const fullName = document.getElementById('firstname').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('lastName').value;
```

There are of course other ways to get these values and this assumes there will be a value but you get the gist.